# Nodejs AWS Lambda switching to another accounts access and secret key to perform functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I am using Node with lambda and the AWS Javascript SDK. I have a role attached to the lambda function that allows the access I need to do. I want to be able to accept user input of access and secret keys and update my AWS config to perform new actions with those updated credentials. So far

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");  // I do the normal import 
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});  // do some dynamo action
```

....

Then use these keys that have rights to another accounts resources

```
AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId: data.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey
});
```

When I perform a new task it just uses the permissions provided with the lambda role and not the updated AWS creds. Any ideas?

Comment: Try creating a new client AFTER you set those credentials (`let ddb2 = new AWS.DynamoDB(...`).

Comment: I just tried that and have the same issue.

Comment: Try passing the credentials directly to the DynamoDB client constructor like: `new AWS.DynamoDB({
    accessKeyId: data.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey
})`. Also make sure `data.accessKey` and `data.secretAccessKey` have the values you think they do during the execution of the Lambda function. If they aren't set correctly, then you are just passing `null` which would mean it would fall back to the Lambda execution role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update the AWS.config, it updates the AWS object. Any AWS Service objects (S3, EC2, DynamoDB, ...) objects created ***since*** then will have the updated credentials. It will not update any service objects created ***before*** the update to AWS.config.

As AWS Guru @johnrotenstein suggested, you should create your service object **after** updating the config. If you `ddb` object is already created at this time, just redeclare it as a `new DynamoDB({...})`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId: data.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey
})
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'})
```

Another possibly simpler solution is to use the update method on the service object's config attribute as such:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'})
ddb.config.update({accessKeyId: '', secretAccessKey: ''})
// ddb will now use the new credentials for future calls
```

Comment: `AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId: data.accessKey,
    secretAccessKey: data.secretAccessKey
})` this will globally set the access key and id and won't allow to use resources in same account.